# How can I incorporate the command line option --max-http-header-size=15000 into my nexe or pkg executable in node js?

Tags: node.js, flags, response-headers, nexe

In my program, one of the requests I send throws a Header Overflow error upon receiving response. I am currently able to run my program in the command line using `node --max-http-header-size=15000 app.js`, but now I would like to compile the program as an executable using npm packages like pkg and nexe.  I have tried too use both, and have found no ways of incorporating `--max-http-header-size=15000` in pkg.  With nexe, I was able to create a compiler with the following code:

```
const { compile } = require('nexe')

compile({
  input: './app.js',
  flags: ['--max-http-header-size 20000'],
  targets: 'windows-x64-12.16.3'
}).then(() => {
  console.log('success')
})
```

However, this has not worked effectively in avoiding the Header Overflow error I get if I were to run `node app.js` in the command line without adjusting the max header size. I have also ran `nexe app.js -f --max-http-header-size=15000 -t windows-x64-12.16.3` in the terminal and had no success avoiding the overflow error. If it helps, I am using Axios as my request library.  Any help is appreciated, thank you!